# ¿Query en laravel con Relationships desde blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Buenas tengo las siguientes tablas

- Users
- Solicitudes
- Servidores
  Las cuales estan relacionadas de la siguiente manera.

  - Un Usuario tiene varias Solicitudes
  - Un Servidor tiene varias Solicitudes

Ahora lo que requiero es obtener todo los servidores asociados a las solicitudes que tiene el usuario sin repeticiones.

Cabe resaltar que este query debo hacerlo en la vista blade ya que en la vista estoy recorriendo los servicios y mostrándolos en una tabla.

Estos servidores que tiene el usuario asociados a sus solicitudes las debo mostrar en un input pero eso es lo facil.

Hasta el momento he estado intentando con lo siguiente

```
@foreach($solicitudes as $solicitud)    
@php


    $serversUser = \App\Servidor::where('solicitudesDeServicio', function($query){
                                                        $query->where('user_id',$solicitud->user->id);
                                                    });
                                                @endphp
@endforeach
```

Pero no ha funcionado ya que la variable $solicitud->user->id no me la reconoce y me arroja la excecion **Undefined variable: solicitud**

Entonces como se podría obtener los servidores que tiene un usuario asociados a su solicitud sin repeticiones.

Modelo del Servidor:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Servidor extends Model
{
    protected $table = "servers";
    protected $fillable = ['url','username','password'];

    public function solicitudesDeServicio(){
      return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo de la solicitudes

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SolicitudServicio extends Model
{
  protected $table ="solicitudes";
  protected $fillable = ['url', 'servicio', 'servicio_id', 'nequipos', 'nequipos_asignados','username','password', 'ndias'];
//Metodo del operador
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
  }

  public function servicio(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Servicio::class);
  }
  public function estado(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Estado::class); //es estado de solicitud
  }

  public function tipo(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Tipo::class); //Es tipo de solicitud
  }
  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  public function ciudad(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Ciudad::class);
  }
  public function servidor(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Servidor::class);
  }
}
```

Controlador de la vista

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\SolicitudServicio;
use Auth;
use App\Estado;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Contacto;
use App\Components\SOAPRequests;

class Solicitudes extends Controller
{



  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('isOperador');

    }


  public function view(Request $data){

      //Se agregan los filtros de la vista
      if($data->has('estado') && $data->estado == 'act'){

          //Obtengo todos los datos del filtro pero solo del usuaio logueado
          //Voy a ver si el usuario es administrador
          foreach (Auth::user()->roles as $rol) {
            if($rol->name == 'adm'){
              $registroSolicitudes = SolicitudServicio::whereHas('estado', function($query){
                $query->where('name', 'act');
              })->paginate(6)->appends('estado',$data->estado);
            }elseif($rol->name == 'opr'){
              $registroSolicitudes = Auth::user()->solicitudedeServicios()->whereHas('estado', function($eq){
                $eq->where('name', 'act');
              })->paginate(6)->appends('estado',$data->estado);;
            }
          }

      }else if($data->has('estado') && $data->estado == 'pnt'){
          //Obtengo todos lo registro en blanco y que lo pagine
          $registroSolicitudes = SolicitudServicio::whereHas('estado', function($query){
            $query->where('name', 'pnt');
          })->paginate(6)->appends('estado',$data->estado);
      }else if($data->has('estado') && $data->estado == 'fnl'){
            //Obtengo todos lo registro en blanco y que lo pagine
            $registroSolicitudes = SolicitudServicio::whereHas('estado', function($query){
              $query->where('name', 'fnl');
            })->paginate(6)->appends('estado',$data->estado);
      }else{
          //Sin filtros
          //Se muestran tanto en blanco como completados del usuario
          if(Auth::user()->isRol('adm')){
            $registroSolicitudes = SolicitudServicio::whereHas('estado', function($query){
              $query->where('name', 'pnt');
            })->orWherehas('estado',function($eq){
                $eq->where('name', 'act');
              })->orWherehas('estado',function($eq){
                  $eq->where('name', 'fnl');
                })->paginate(6);
          }else{
            $registroSolicitudes = SolicitudServicio::whereHas('estado', function($query){
              $query->where('name', 'pnt');
              })->orWherehas('users',function($eq){
                $eq->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
              })->paginate(6);
          }
      }

      //$soapR = new SOAPRequests();





      return view('operador.listaSolicitudes',['solicitudes'=>$registroSolicitudes] );


  }
```

Modelo de usuario

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'roles',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token','profesion_id'
    ];


    public function roles(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Rol::class);
    }

    public function provedores(){
      return $this->hasMany(ProveedorLogin::class);
    }
    //Metodo para el operador
    public function solicitudedeServicios(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(SolicitudServicio::class);
    }
    public function solicitudes(){
      return $this->hasMany(SolicitudServicio::class);
    }

    //Funcion Para comprboar roles
    public function isRol($losroles){
      $resultado = false;
      foreach (explode("|",$losroles) as $elrol) {
        foreach ($this->roles as $rol) {
          if($rol->name == $elrol){
            $resultado = true;
          }
        }
      }

      return $resultado;
    }

    public function profesion(){
      return $this->belongsTo(ProfesionUser::class);
    }

    public function company(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de los 3 modelos y el del controlador.

Answer (score 2):

tienes un error en tu consulta, te falta el `use($solicitud)` despues del `function($query)` por eso te da error **Undefined variable: solicitud**:

```
@foreach($solicitudes as $solicitud)    
  @php
    $serversUser = \App\Servidor::where('solicitudesDeServicio', function($query) use($solicitud) {
      $query->where('user_id',$solicitud->user->id);
    });
  @endphp
@endforeach
```

y para obtener todos los registros sin repetir puedes usar la función `distinct()` del query builder de laravel: [Query builder Docs Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#selects)

**Nota**: Te recomiendo que no uses los campos de las tablas en camelcase, localmente esto te puede funcionar pero en algunos servidores esto te puede dar errores o dolores de cabeza.

Answer (score 2):

**NO es una buena práctica hacer una consulta en la vista.**

El segundo problema que tienes con ese método de la vista es que harás muchas solicitudes a la base de datos, y eso también es una mala práctica, además de un problema potencial de rendimiento.

---

Ahora, la consulta aparentemente la puedes hacer muy fácil desde el controlador por medio de Eager Loading de los modelos asociados, a menos que no entienda bien el problema:

```
$registroSolicitudes = SolicitudServicio::with('servidor')
    ->whereHas('estado', function($query){
            $query->where('name', 'act');
    })
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

Para más información, revisa la documentación de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading